# Matrix and vector multiplication, outputting incorrect product

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I've created a Vector and Matrix class and I am trying to perform operations such as the multiplication of a matrix and vector, the multiplication of a matrix and matrix, and the multiplication of a matrix and a float (scalar). I seem to be having problem getting the right product for the matrix * vector and matrix * matrix. 
Here is the part of Matrix class meant to handle those operations:

```
// Matrix * vector, result vector
Vector Matrix::operator*(const Vector & other) const
{
if (other.getDimensions() == 4)
{
    float floats[4];
    const float* temp = other.getData();
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        Vector myCol = column(j);
        floats[j] = (temp[0] * myCol.getData(0)) + (temp[1] * myCol.getData(1)) + (temp[2] * myCol.getData(2)) + (temp[3] * myCol.getData(3));
    }
    return Vector(floats[0], floats[1], floats[2], floats[3]);
}
else
{
    return Vector();
}
}

// Matrix * scalar, result matrix
Matrix Matrix::operator*(float c) const 
{
Matrix myMatrix;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    myMatrix.data[i] = this->data[i] * c;
}
return myMatrix;
}
```

In my main.cpp,

```
Matrix m = Matrix(Vector(1, 0, 0, 1), Vector(0, 1, 0, 2), Vector(0, 0, 1, 3), Vector(0, 0, 0, 1));
```

Is the value of the matrix and

```
    v = Vector(1, 0, -1, 1);
```

Is the value of the vector. 
When I multiply m * v I get <1, 0, -1, -1>, but the answer is <2, 2, 2, 1>.

And when doing the matrix * scalar with the same m matrix above and vector v with the values

```
v = Vector(1, 0, -1, 0);
```

I get m*v to be <1, 0, -1, 2> when it should be <1, 0, -1, 0>. 
My Vector class works fine so I'm suspecting I messed up somewhere with the math for implementing the matrix operations.

Comment: Isn't a `Vector` simply a Matrix with one column?  If so, why make `Vector` a separate class and why write a separate routine for multiplication of a Matrix and Vector when `Matrix * Matrix` should work anyway?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The Vector class was meant to represent multiple mathematical vectors of different dimensions. It was part of the assignment. We were meant to practice implementing multiple classes with memory management, pointers, operator overloading, ect.

Comment: A Matrix multiplied by a vector yields a new matrix, not a vector .  Why are you returning a Vector?  In addition, even if a `Vector` was returned, why return a default `Vector` on an error?  I am assuming that a default `Vector` has valid values as any other vector, and if that's the case, the caller has no idea the vector being returned is supposed to mean "this is a bad vector".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well it is only supposed to work if the matrix has a dimension of 4. Since the matrix m does have a dimension of 4 it and the vector is 4 x 1 it should return a vector.

Comment: A Matrix consists of rows and columns.  What is meant by "a dimension of 4" for a Matrix?  Second, this all sounds counter-intuitive -- a Matrix multiplied by a Vector, gives you a Matrix -- what you're doing is some made up math that goes against convention.  Third, if a person calls the multiply function, and the dimensions are not 4, how is that person informed that there is an error?  They're not, instead they get a Vector() tossed back at them, which doesn't indicate that something wrong happened -- that's my point.

Comment: I don't understand your "multiplied by a scalar" example. If you want to call your operator*(float) you should do something like `m*5.0f`, and not multiply the matrix by some vector.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, a 4x4 square matrix multiplied by a vector (which can be considered a 4x1 matrix or a column vector) gives a 4x1 matrix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @Klaus answer, mathematically in the expression `M*V` the vector `V` is a *column*, and the elements of the result are (dot-)products of matrix *rows* and `V`. Replace `column(j)` with `row(j)`.

Comment: Well thanks. Apparently I confused the words row and column, that solved the question if the constructor or the operator was wrong... going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I calculated your example by hand now, and if you expect the result to be <2, 2, 2, 1>, then you definitely swapped rows and columns in your matrix. When you multiply a matrix with a vector you want to put the products of the rows of the matrix and the vector in a result vector. Kind of:

```
Vector Matrix::operator*(const Vector & other) const
{
    float floats[4];
    const float* temp = other.getData();
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        Vector my_row = row(j);
        floats[j] = 0;
        for(int i=0; i!=4; ++i)
            floats[j]+=temp[i] * myCol.getData(i);
    }
    //(maybe provide a better constructor to take an array)
    return Vector(floats[0], floats[1], floats[2], floats[3]);
}
```

For the example with the scalar, I don't get the point. I don't understand how you expect a multiplication of a matrix with a scalar if you are multiplying a matrix with a vector.

Also you could improve the error handling by only accepting vectors of size 4 (imposing that as a requirement in your vector class), if you just use vectors of size 4.

PS: maybe you should also put your addition code in the loop, into a second loop, so that it is more readable and expandable.